# how to send an otp to number using twilio in android java

Tags: android, twilio

I'm working on a Java Android project and need to send an OTP to the user's phone using Twilio. Despite searching extensively, I haven't found any comprehensive documentation or blogs explaining the proper way to achieve this. Could someone guide me on the correct approach or provide relevant resources for integrating Twilio to send OTPs in an Android application

Answer (score 2):

For SMS OTP (One Time Password) you would need to use the Twilio Verify API. This doesn't require you to purchase a Twilio phone number. Based on the link that you posted above it looks like you'll be writing this in Java. Here is a link to the [Verify API in Java that shows how to instantiate a Verify Service, send a OTP token, and verify the token](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api?code-sample=code-step-1-create-a-verification-service&code-language=Java&code-sdk-version=8.x).

Please let me know if you have any other questions.